# Limpar o autopreenchimento dos formulários asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Eu tenho uma tela de cadastro onde observei que quando o usuário deixa o navegador gravar o cache, quando ele vai preencher sempre vem uma lista de informações que já foram digitadas, eu gostaria de limpar estas informações de forma que não oferecessem estas informações digitadas. Detalhe, estou usando session, não então não poderia interferi.

Agradeço

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em [ASP](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/kb/234067), para impedir o cache de formulários, você pode usar

```html
<% Response.CacheControl = "no-cache" %>
<% Response.AddHeader "Pragma", "no-cache" %>
<% Response.Expires = -1 %>
```

Você pode usar diretamente o seguinte HTML:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
```

E também, no formulário, você pode incluir a propriedade `autocomplete="off"`

Comment: Se eu usar isso, pode todas as páginas não vão guardar um cache ou é melhor usar apenas na pagina especifica.

Comment: Coloca as meta tags na master page e, se não resolver, coloca `autocomplete="off"` no formulário: `<form autocomplete="off" name="formulario" action="minha_pagina.aspx" method="POST">`

Comment: agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Resolveu seu problema?

Comment: no momento sim, vou testar em todos os outros navegadores